# Parsley raising errors on fields that are not on the page

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

Is it possible to ignore validation errors that are raised when a field is no longer on the page?

I have a form that dynamically inserts and adds validation, I don't have control over the code that removes the field however, so removing the validation before it does remove the field isn't possible.

Instead I was hoping that there's a way to catch all field/form errors and reject the error if the field no longer exists on the page.

Is this possible?

I've tried destroying and re-initializing the form but that's not ideal at all.

Answer (score 0):

Parsley automatically re-scans for inputs within the form. If your input isn't in the form / page, then it won't be part of form validation anymore.

So either it's a bug of Parsley, or you're mistaken in your analysis. Post an example and we'll know for sure!

Comment: It's 100% a bug in the version that I'm using (which obviously wasn't stated)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I know what you mean exactly.. But in case you want to remove an already existing error, you can use `removeError(name, {updateClass = true});` as mentioned [here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-ui-for-javascript)

If you wanted something else, you can always take a look at parsleys default.js which is right [here](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/annotated-source/defaults.html)

Also make sure to provide some code, so that we are able to help you out better.